# Using C Libraries in DLL file for Python

Tags: python, c, dll, libraries

Following my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880528/using-c-dll-with-complex-h-library-in-python-very-slow) I figured out that calling functions from different C libraries, e.g., `math.h` in the `.dll` file from Python slows down the execution.

As far as I understand it's because when you use `math.h` etc. functions in Python, there is an additional step involved in calling these functions from a DLL. This extra step introduces some overhead, as the Python interpreter needs to load the DLL, find the specific function you are using, and then pass the arguments to that function.

One random example:

Using the `abs()` function in C slows down the code when called through the DLL in Python.

Instead I use the following function, which runs fast:

```
double myabs(double r, double i) {
    return sqrt(r*r + i*i);
}
```

So my main question would be **is there a way to call the C libraries in the DLL without increasing the runtime?**

Note: I observed significant increased runtime when the library functions are called within a loop and not just once. However running the code just in C and not as a DLL in Python works fine.